# Singleton keep initializing?

Tags: blazor

I am trying to share data between classes, and I am normally so far were using in WinForms this approach, which seems like doesn't works in Blazor.

```
public class MainConfiguration
{
        private static MainConfiguration _instance = null;
        public static MainConfiguration instance
        { 
            get
            {
                if( _instance == null )
                    _instance = new MainConfiguration();

                return _instance;
            }            

        }

        public MainConfiguration()
        {
        }
}
```

- why **instance** keep initializing in each request ? and
- How to properly create a singleton in Blazor ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register you MainConfiguration as a singleton service in the Startup.cs:

```
services.AddSingleton<MainConfiguration>();
```

Then inject it everywhere you need to have access to:

e.g. in a .razor file you can either do:

```
@inject MainConfiguration MainConfiguration
```

or in the `@code` section:

```
[Inject]
public MainConfiguration MainConfiguration {get; set;}
```

You can also inject your MainConfiguration into a c# class via the constructor:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(MainConfiguration mainConfiguration) { ... }
}
```

Comment: but if I get rid of the "instance" how do I use it inside a normal C# class then

Comment: The dependency injection takes care that for you.
Just inject the type with annotation mentioned above or use inject it in the class constructor. 
public SomeClass(SomethingToInject _instance) => ....

Comment: I really were wondering if i can skip somehow the singleton as a constructor parameter, but seems like all examples pointing toward it.